FE1.1S-based USB hub not being recognized
I made an FE1.1S-based USB hub 4 layer PCB. It worked fine at first, then it stopped responding. I tried to solder a new IC, but It's still not working and shows a message “not recognized” from the laptop.
I measured the output voltages on the capacitors and it gave 4.2V instead of 3.3V and 2.8V instead of 1.8V.
The input 5V also gets dropped to 4.9 when plugged in. Are both IC’s toast?
Or what could be the issue here?



We unfortunately don't have a crystal ball for remote debugging the issue. You need to show schematics, PCB layout, used cables and wiring, so that anyone could be able to replicate to see the same issue you are experiencing, and then do local debugging.

I measured the output voltages on the capacitors and it gave 4.2V and 2.8V instead of 3.3V and 1.8V. The input 5V also gets dropped to 4.9 when plugged in. Sounds like something is overloading the entire supply line. I'd measure the current drawn from each rail.

What are those reverse LEDs good for?

my 2 cent comment: I once had issue with an onboard USB hub working erratically. It was my choice of the oscillator: it wasn't stable enough. I used a +-40ppm instead of a +-10ppm oscillator as suggested in the datasheet...

@RohatKılıç These rails are outputs from the USB HUB Controller and input to the USB hub controller again. I only have an indicator led on the 3.3V and decoupling capacitors. nothing is connected to the 1.8V rail except decoupling capacitors as shown in the schematics.

@Justme I had the schematics attached and i just edited the post and added the layout. As for the cables, I used 28awg Male DC barrel jack for power wired directly from a 5v adapter. Let me know if anything else is missing

@Blup1980 I used a +-10ppm 12MHZ crystal. So, unfortunately that shouldnt be the issue.

@Lundin These are just port led indicators which tells which port is active. Took it straight from the datasheet and they were working fine when the pcb was working

Are the negative pins of C2 and C3 connected to GND? If they accidentially are connected to +5 V, the over time rising reverse leakage current would explain the issue.

@Jens Yes connected to ground. It seems that i damaged the ic's one way or another since it outputs higher voltages on the designated pins.
